# Changing windowTitleBackgroundStyle

Tags: java, android, android-styles

## windowTitleBackgroundStyle is not working

I am trying to set app's window title background a gradient, but it doesn't affect. So, please help me to fix this issue.

*styles.xml*

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomMenuTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomMenuTitle">
    <item name="android:textSize">40dip</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient</item>
</style>
```

*manifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.davud.codeit">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".CodeItActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomMenuTitle</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/CustomTitleStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">60dp</item>
</style>


<style name="CustomMenuTitle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTitleStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorblue</item>
</style>
```

and extend YourActivity with Activity

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't help.